# Isolated scope for directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having some troubles understanding isolated scopes in Angular directives. I've read the official documentation, watched a lot of videos about the subject, so now I'm know what's the purpose of them, but I'm not sure how to use them.

Here is a simple example.
I created a directive called `searchBox` (see [full source and demo](http://jsbin.com/IWOKUGi/1/edit))

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('searchBox', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element) {                
      scope.open = false;

      // Show search input
      scope.showInput = function() {
        scope.open = true;

        // Focus the input
        $timeout(function() {
          element.find('input').focus();
        }, 0);
      };

      // Hide search input
      scope.hideInput = function() {
        scope.open = false;
      };
    }
  }
});
```

and this actually works as expected. However, I want to isolate the scope of the directive, but if I change `scope: true` to `scope: {}` (see [full source and demo](http://jsbin.com/IWOKUGi/2/edit))) it no longer works, but I can't see any errors in the console.

I'm sure it's something elementary I'm doing wrong, but I really hope somebody can open my eyes and help me understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Got it working](http://jsbin.com/IWOKUGi/9/edit).

The problem was that the directive should include it's own template (or have the [transclude option set to true](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements)) because you are wrapping other elements.

If other directives (like ng-click or ng-blur) are defined inside a template in the `search-box` directive, they get evaluated against the search-box $scope. But if there isn't a template, they bubble up to the parent $scope (which, in this case, doesn't have the functions showInput() or hideInput(), etc).

If you don't want to have the html string in the directive's declaration, you can use the `templateUrl` option to reference external templates.

Comment: Nice catch. Slight correction though: if you don't specify the template for the directive, other directives (ng-click, ng-blur) get bubbled up to the parent's scope. See here: http://jsbin.com/IWOKUGi/7/edit